# Failed to install ubuntu 12.10 on asrock h77 pro4/mvp with uefi bios

Tags: system-installation, usb, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I want to install the ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04 desktop for my new pc.

steps:
I created a bootable USB, config the bios to boot from the USB drive.
pressed "Try Ubuntu before you installing" Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 on my new desktop,
It failed.

What I tried after it failed:

1. I have tested the USB drive image without any error.
2. There are guys suggested to disable secure boot for UEFI bios, tried but failed.
3. I tried pressing F2 to see the log, it shown as below
   generating locale....
   DONE
   and the process hanged.

Specs:

mobo: ASRock h77 pro4/mvp
CPU: Xeon e3 1245

try then install, because people recommended to Try Ubuntu before installing. It can make sure Ubuntu will run on your desktop.

I  read the recommended post(to disable Secure Boot), it still can't solve my problems

Comment: Pressing "Try Ubuntu before you install it" *does not* install it. You need to select 'Install Ubuntu 12.x' instead.

Comment: Why is it failing, can you describe where are you getting stuck or what do you see on the screen? Any error messages or faults?

Comment: @Mochan Or select *Try Ubuntu* and then run the installer from the desktop.

Comment: i can install ubuntu after dsiconnect the dvd-rom

Answer (score 1):

### What options are there when booting Ubuntu from a USB or CD?

You have two options when booting from a bootable USB or using a LiveCD.

**The first option is:**

### Try Ubuntu

[image: Try Ubuntu]

The **Try Ubuntu** option allows you to try Ubuntu without permanently installing it and altering your system. It creates a environment, run by the files on your CD/USB and using the hardware on your computer. While in this state, your hard-disk is not affected and no changes are permanently made to your system.

**The second option is:**

### Install Ubuntu

[image: Install Ubuntu]

The **Install Ubuntu** option *permanently* (unless you want to [remove it](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/)) installs Ubuntu onto your computer, and from that point on will use your hard-drive to save files and to operate off. If you choose to dual-boot with Windows or OS X, you are able to choose which one to start at the boot of your computer.

### Which should I use?

1. If you are looking to *test* Ubuntu, you should:

   - Choose the **Try Ubuntu** option, or
   - [Install Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox), which can be deleted and won't override your previous OS.
2. If you wish to *permanently install* Ubuntu, you should:

   - Choose the **Install Ubuntu** option, and
   - Run it alongside (dual-boot) Microsoft Windows, Apple OS X, or another OS you have installed, or
   - Replace your old OS with Ubuntu. Please not that this will **remove all files and data on the other OS.**

Depending on what you want to do, you must choose the right option!

### Good luck!

Comment: i already tested "Try Ubuntu" option but failed by a bootable usb. Is there any other options ? thanks

Comment: Do you want to **install** Ubuntu, or just try it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the user is complaining about. pretty sure he knows how to boot either to try or install, but something is going wrong.

Comment: to Bruno Pereira

when i choose try ubuntu before install it, there is only black screen with blinking underscore....then it stop blinking....

Comment: when i can boot into the ubuntu loading screen, and i pressed F2, the screen shown:  stdin: Not a typewriter  stdin: Not a typewriter  Generating locales...  en_US.UTF-8... done  Generation complete. then stoped there.

Comment: can boot into ubuntu after disconnect the dvdrom....